# Concatenate columns in SQL query result from a single table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have query that looks something like the following:

```
select firstname, lastname
from names
where firstname = 'john'
```

I would like to have something like the following (conceptually):

```
select
[names.firstname + names.lastname] as 'fullname'
from names
where names.firstname = 'john'
```

Of course, this returns an invalid column name 'names.firstname + names.lastname'.

Is it possible to return a single aliased column containing the result of two columns from the same table?

Comment: select
    [firstname] +', ' +[lastname] as 'fullname'
    from names
    where names.firstname = 'john'

Comment: What version of SQL Server? What is the desired result if either column is null?

Comment: The [concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function might be an option if your server version is 2012+

Comment: @MartinSmith, SQL Server 2012; If either column is null, I suppose a blank would be fine. Although I might consider catching null cases with something like ISNULL(firstname, '(No First Name) ') ?

Comment: The reason you got that error was because of the brackets you put around the expression. And don't use quotes around the alias.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments; In this case it looks like the following will work as needed:

```
    CONCAT(ISNULL(names.FirstName, '(No First Name)', 
           ' ', ISNULL(names.LastName, '(No Last Name)')) AS 'FullName'
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from the alias.